# 3D collision response advice for programming generic physics engine

Tags: game-physics, collision

My problem is handling collisions when rigidbodies are just sitting on eachother. Like one cube stacked on top of the other, or a cube sitting on a static mesh, and having them realistically settle into place and not seemingly balance on a corner or an edge.

I am making a voxel engine in Unity, I am doing my own collision detection to avoid using Unity's very slow collider baking function that needs to run every time the mesh is updated. So far it is going really great.

My problem is I can't realistically get rigid bodies to settle into place while sitting on a static mesh. My collision detection system works for slow speeds, which is all I need right now, I just use the positions of the vertices of the rigidbody mesh, it's just that if I have, say, a cube-shaped rigid body, it will stop falling when it collides with a static mesh, like it is supposed to, but it will just balance on a corner or an edge.

So I apply a force at the position of the collision to rotate it around and settle it into place, but this not only results in the rigidbody vibrating wildly after settling into place, but it just doesn't work very well in general, it does not look realistic. So I was wondering if there was a better way to handle these collisions or if you guys had any ideas at all. Trying to research this has been very hard because all that shows up in my searches is just on how to handle rigidbody-rigidbody collisions, or if it isn't, they only talk about how to handle that initial moment of collision and say nothing about how to get it to settle into place. I'll take any ideas at all. Thank you.

Comment: I think you'd have better luck asking this on the game development stackexchange (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), since conceptual questions that don't include a block of code usually aren't a good fit here

Comment: Ok thank you I will do that

Comment: I think you should not apply a force at the point of contact but a torque with the collision point being the static point of rotation (i.e. a pivoting point). After all, you want the body to rotate around that point until it settles. The torque should possibly be a damping torque (like a vector pointing from the pivoting point to the point at which a damping force is applied cross product with the vector of the damping force). And by the way, does gravity act on the rigid bodies? If yes, this damping torque should be damping the motion due to gravitational torque around the pivoting point.

Comment: @Futurologist thank you I thought that way would be difficult because how do you decide what the pivot would be with multiple points touching?

Comment: I am not sure what scenarios you encounter. If you provide a picture/diagram or a more detailed description of a situation which you would like to resolve, it may be helpful. If you have more than one contact point, then you may have a pivoting axis, rather than a pivoting point. Or if you have too many contact points, then no rotation should be taking place and maybe the body is already stationary? I do not know what the static mesh looks like and what the body typically looks like. But if you have a box on top of a plane, balancing on one corner (i.e. vertex), then the torque is an option.

Comment: Consider using verlet integration as it makes it easier to manage forces and balance the energy of the system . Energy must be conserved. Growth of oscillation artifacts when a system is in a low energy state is a sign that the system is incorrectly gaining energy (most likely coming from the force you apply to rotate the body) When a body is resting the net force is zero. A point in contact (not sliding) becomes a pivot and has no force applied at that point. Rotational forces must come from the center of mass when a point is in static contact.